# position absolute not working in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

this is html:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="iefile">
</form>
<form>
    <input type="file" id="iefile">
</form>
```

this is css:

```
form{
    position:relative;
}
#iefile{
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;right:-20px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

and this is output in ie8:

[image]

I have 10 form.but in the above I enter 2 form.I want to put all input together .that work on firefox and chrome .but ie8 have problem

Comment: You are using the same id more than once, id should be unique! try using a class instead

Comment: I use class but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Declare a doctype. I'd encourage you to use the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```